# How to move some specific folder keeping a predefined directory structure?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, directory-structure

I have a directory containing about 7k folders. These folders were extracted from zips and some of the extraction was done using Python scripts. Some of these folders are extracted in such a way that

```
             Main Dir
                |
         ---------------
        |               |
      fold1            fold2
        |               |
      ------         -------
    |        |          |
  .pngs   .txts       fold2
                        |
                     -------
                    |       |
                  .pngs    .txts
```

The requirement is to move the `fold2` category of folders in a directory structure similar to that of `fold1` where a folder contains the data instead of another same named folder containing the data.

How may I do it using bash or command line so that I have all 7k folders in a homogeneous structure similar to `fold1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will search the current working directory for paths of the form `a/B/B/c` and compress them to `a/B/c`. This also compresses `a/B/B/B/B/c` to `a/B/c` and `a/B/B/c/D/D/e` to `a/B/c/D/e`.

You need GNU `find` to use the `-regextype` option and an implementation of `mv` supporting `-n`. If you don't have these please have a look at the unsafe posix version at the end of the script.

```
shopt -s dotglob failglob
find . -depth -regextype egrep -type d -regex '.*/([^/]*)/\1' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' path; do
  mv -n -t "$path/.." "$path"/* &&
  rmdir "$path"
done
```

Arbitrary path names (whitespaces, special symbols like `*`, and even linebreaks) are supported.

The command makes sure *not* to overwrite or delete any files. In a situation as in the left tree the repeated sub-directory has to be kept. You will get the error message `rmdir: failed to remove './A/A'`. The result can be seen to the right.

```
. (before)               . (after)
└── A                    └── A
    ├── someFile             ├── someFile
    ├── collision            ├── collision
    └── A                    ├── anotherFile
        ├── collision        └── A
        └── anotherFile          └── collision
```

Hidden files are copied too.

#### Bad Posix Version

A more portable version of the script which cannot handle line breaks inside paths, may overwrite files in situations as the one shown above, and cannot move hidden files (sub-directory is kept if there are hidden files inside).

```
find . -depth -type d | grep -E -x '.*/([^/]*)/\1' |
while IFS= read -r path; do
  mv "$path"/* "$path/.." &&
  rmdir "$path"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's what you need but...

```
mv /maindir/fold2/ /maindir/renamed/
mv /maindir/renamed/fold2/ /maindir/fold2/
```

then, *renamed* should be empty, delete it.

or this should do the job too

```
mv maindir/fold2/fold2/{*,.*} maindir/fold2/
```

then */maindir/fold2/fold2/* should be empty

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wanted. You only showed how to move one folder manually but OP has 7000 of them. Also, the last `mv` command will give two error messages since `.*` also matches `.` and `..`.

Comment: Well, there is not that much details in his question, that's why I posted what I could understand in it. And about the "error" message, it's fine.

Comment: On arch linux and ubuntu I get two warnings from the last command (as expected). Don't you get errors too for the following test case? `mkdir a a/a a/a/b; mv a/a/{*,.*} a/`.